# Additional cost for shipping method when choosing cash on delivery

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a courier shipping method with a cost of 3.5€ and what I will need is when someone chooses the specific shipping method and payment by cash on delivery, the shipping cost changes from 3.5€ to 5€.

Please advise me.

I tried to make a second shipping method and only show it on cash on delivery but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This function will check if the selected shipping method is your courier shipping method and if the payment method is cash on delivery. If both conditions are met, it will modify the shipping cost to 5€. Here's an example of how you can implement this function:

```
function change_shipping_cost_based_on_payment_method($rates, $package) {
$chosen_shipping_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0];
$chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

// Check if the chosen shipping method is your courier shipping method
if ($chosen_shipping_method === 'your_courier_shipping_method') {
    // Check if the chosen payment method is cash on delivery
    if ($chosen_payment_method === 'cod') {
        foreach ($rates as $rate_key => $rate) {
            // Change the shipping cost to 5€
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 5;
            $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = array_map('wc_format_decimal', $rates[$rate_key]->taxes);
        }
    }
}

return $rates;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_shipping_cost_based_on_payment_method', 10, 2);
```

Make sure to replace 'your_courier_shipping_method' with the actual slug or ID of your courier shipping method. Also, ensure that 'cod' matches the payment method slug for cash on delivery in your WooCommerce settings.

Comment: I added these but it didn't work:                                                                                                                  if ($chosen_shipping_method === 'shipping_method_0_flat_rate10') {
    // Check if the chosen payment method is cash on delivery
    if ($chosen_payment_method === 'payment_method_cod') {